# How to correctly use MATLAB datestr function?

Tags: matlab, date

I have a timestamp number

1499664147.116744566

===============================

I put the number into a website. It showed

The corresponding date and time should be

GMT: Monday, July 10, 2017 5:22:27.116 AM 
Your time zone: Sunday, July 9, 2017 10:22:27.116 PM GMT-07:00 DST

=================================

However, it shows '22.12.5940.02.48.726' if I use datestr

datestr(1499664147.116744566,'dd.mm.yyyy.HH.MM.FFF')

May I know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that MATLAB doesn't use epoch time which is represented as seconds since Midnight Jan 1, 1970. Instead it takes in time in days with a different base. Use the following to generate the correct time.

```
epoch_time = datenum('01-01-1970','mm-dd-yyyy');
t_sec = 1499664147.11674;
t_days = t_sec / (60*60*24);
t_str = datestr(t_days + epoch_time, 'dd.mm.yyyy.HH.MM.SS.FFF')
```

which results in

`10.07.2017.05.22.27.117`

I guessed that you wanted seconds to be displayed since you have `FFF` in the format string so I added the `SS` before that.